# Simulink - export a model in a single file

Tags: export, block, libraries, simulink

How can I create a single simulink file from a simulink model, which consists of mutliple linked blocks in user defined block libraries?

In other words I am looking for a way to break all the library links and have the whole model exist in its own file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by saving the file using `save_system` in the Matlab command window, eg. `save_system('mysys','mynewfile.mdl','BreakUserLinks','true')`. This will break all your library links and save the whole model in one file.

See also `help save_system`